# Search result on the basis of dimensions of product

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am new to jQuery, want to make a search box like below image I am sharing to you.

This search box should show result on the pressing enter key of keyboard.
This search box is having fields `Length`, `Width`, `Height`" and a drop-down to specify measurement units like `inch` and `mm`.

[image]

Comment: Let's hire a personal developer, so can command to do assigned task!

Comment: Agree with @Vikrant

Comment: Check [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) for reference.

Comment: did you found solution ? may be some free extension will help also did you set the attribute `dimension` to `yes` under attributes ?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Thank you for your help

Comment: Please share the efforts you made so far